# Unmatched query written in visual basic

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am pretty new to this stuff and am stuck on this for a while now.
So basically I want to write a code in VB which would take a column from one table (Table A) and compare it with some other column in a different table (Table B). Now I want the missing elements in Table A from Table B, to be copied in Table A (just that single column and not the whole row). I would love to get a basic syntax for this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No VBA needed.
Use the Query Wizard and "Find Unmatched Query Wizard", then just add `INSERT INTO ([field name])` at the top.

For example, I have Table1.[Column 1] containing some letters of the alphabet, I then have Table2.Column2 containing all letters of the alphabet.
**NB:**  Square brackets around [Column 1] as it has a space in it.

The wizard will give me:

```
SELECT Table2.Column2
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[Column2] = Table1.[Column 1]
WHERE (((Table1.[Column 1]) Is Null));
```

bit of tidying up in Notepad++ and I have:

```
SELECT  Column2
FROM    Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[Column2] = Table1.[Column 1]
WHERE   [Column 1] Is Null
```

**NB**: I've removed the table names from the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses as `Column2` is unique to `Table2` and `Column 1` is unique to `Table1`.  You only have to name use the table names if the column name appears in more than one table.

Finally, I just add the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1([Column 1])
SELECT  Column2
FROM    Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[Column2] = Table1.[Column 1]
WHERE   [Column 1] Is Null
```

**Final NB:**  The LEFT JOIN signifies that all values are returned from Table2 (as it's on the left of the join) and only those values that match the join criteria are returned from Table1 (on the right of the join) - turn LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN to reverse this (or put the tables the other way around).  The WHERE clause then removes the values that appear in both tables.

To use in code any of these will do it:

```
Sub Test()

    With DoCmd
        .SetWarnings False
        .OpenQuery "Query3"
        .SetWarnings True
    End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1 ( [Column 1] ) " & _
                      "SELECT Column2 " & _
                      "FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[Column2] = Table1.[Column 1] " & _
                      "WHERE [Column 1] Is Null"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "INSERT INTO Table1 ( [Column 1] ) " & _
                                           "SELECT Column2 " & _
                                           "FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[Column2] = Table1.[Column 1] " & _
                                           "WHERE [Column 1] Is Null")
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ! This works great. But now I actually am just curious how to execute the same thing in VBA. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Have added three examples of running the query through VBA.